# JavaScript: sort an array of timestamps with day–month–year format

Tags: javascript

I have an array of timestamps or strings that are of this format - day–month–year.
e.g
`['03-11-2018', '04-12-2018', '10-01-2017', '10-12-2017']`

And I want to sort them chronologically so the above array would become `[ '10-01-2017', '10-12-2017', '03-11-2018', '04-12-2018' ]`

I am aware that you can [use `moment.js`](https://gist.github.com/onildoaguiar/6cf7dbf9e0f0b8684eb5b0977b40c5ad) to do this but I want to write this by hand without using any 3rd lib.

Here is my attempt:

```js
function sortTimestamp(array) {
  array.sort((time1, time2) => {
    const [day1, month1, year1] = time1.split('-')
    const [day2, month2, year2] = time2.split('-')
    return year2 > year1
      ? -1
      : year2 < year1
      ? 1
      : month2 > month1
      ? -1
      : month2 > month1
      ? 1
      : day2 > day1
      ? -1
      : 1
  })
}
```

It works ok but it is not really readable and it is a very imperative approach.  I wonder if there is a better way to do it and also ideally it can be **extended** to support that other date formats e.g. month–day–year.

Comment: Convert the strings to `Date` objects and compare those. `return (new Date(time1)) - (new Date(time2));` Even better, convert the original list to `Date`s.

Comment: You say "day-month-year", but 21 is not a valid month.

Comment: Your comparison function doesn't return `0` if the dates are equal.

Comment: Your example dates look like month-day-year.

Comment: @trincot sorry I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to specify with extra arguments what the format is (regex) and how it should be reordered to ISO-style YYYYMMDD format. Then the function can perform that replacement and do a lexical sort:

```js
function sortTime(array, regex, iso) {
    let fmt = time => time.replace(regex, iso);
    return array.sort((time1, time2) => 
        fmt(time1).localeCompare(fmt(time2)));
}

// demo
let dates = ['03-11-2018', '04-12-2018', '10-01-2017', '10-12-2017'];
let result = sortTime(dates, /(..)-(..)-(....)/, "$3$2$1");
console.log(result);
```

So if the input should be interpreted as mm-dd-yyyy instead of dd-mm-yyyy, then make the third argument "$3$1$2" instead of "$3$2$1".

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! is `localeCompare` necessary here? I haven't used it before

Comment: It is the way to compare strings and get an integer result (-1, 0, 1). There are other ways of course. If the `iso` parameter guarantees that the replacement will only consist of digits and could be evaluated as number for comparison, then you can also do `fmt(time1)-fmt(time2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little simpler using subtraction rather than nested ternaries.

```
function sortTimestamp(array) {
  array.sort((time1, time2) => {
    const [day1, month1, year1] = time1.split('-')
    const [day2, month2, year2] = time2.split('-')
    return year1 - year2 || month1 - month2 || day1 - day2;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert them to Date objects then use the getTime  functionality to compare for sorting. A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

```js
const dates = ['03-11-2018', '04-12-2018', '10-01-2017', '10-21-2017']

sortedDates = dates.sort((a,b)=>{
  const dateA = new Date(a)
  const dateB = new Date(b)
  //change the comparison sign for required orde
  return dateA.getTime() < dateB.getTime() 
  ? 1 
  : -1
 
})
console.log(sortedDates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Craques answer, but added both ASC, DESC sorting using the getTime method

ASC:

```
dates.sort((a,b) => new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime())
```

DESC:

```
dates.sort((a,b) => new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `new Date()` constructor is fairly robust when it comes to interprete date strings. The formats used in the following snippet seem to work reliably:

```js
const a=["2018-09-05","09-21-2018","12/24/2018","19 Sep 2018",'03-11-2018', '04-12-2018', '10-01-2017', '10-21-2017'];

console.log(
  a.map((s,i)=>[new Date(s),i])
   .sort(([a],[b])=>a-b)
   .map(([_,i])=>i+': '+a[i])
)
```

You can leave out the index (`i+': '+`) in the output of course to make it look pretty again.